Multiple levels with different steps for contour series in Plotly.js
Currently we have options to configure the splits of the contour area splits like below,
contours: {
    coloring: 'fill',
    showlabels: false,
    start: 0,   # Start Value
    end: 1,     # End Value
    size: 0.02,  # Size of the split .. so for the give range and size 50 splits will be there
}

#Smaple chart

But, it seems there is no option to configure multiple size for different ranges..
Please let me know if there is any existing way to customize the rage and size like above..
like..
size 0.02 for 0 to 0.5
size 0.04 for 0.5 to 0.8
size 0.08 for 0.8 to 1

